# Solving $(ap)^2-d(bq)^2=1$ for distinct primes $p,q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I'm pondering the following claim regarding special cases of the Pell equation.

**Conjecture:** For every pair of distinct primes $p$ and $q$, there exist integers $a$ and $b$, and a non-square integer $d$, such that $(ap)^2-d(bq)^2=1$.

Is this a known theorem?
Or are there known or easy counterexamples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, in fact, do it with $b=1$, noting that this amounts to looking for a non-square integer of the form

$$d={(ap-1)(ap+1)\over q^2}$$

To find such a $d$, note that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ implies there is a number $a_0$ such that $a_0p\equiv1$ mod $q^2$.  If we now take $a$ of the form $a_0+kq^2$, we see that $ap+1=(a_0p+1)+kpq^2$, which means, by Dirichlet's theorem for primes in airthmetic progressions, we can pick $k$ to make $ap+1=gP$, where where $g=\gcd(a_0p+1,pq^2)$ and $P$ is an arbitrarily large prime, which clearly cannot divide $ap-1$.  For this choice, we have $P\mid d$ but $P^2\not\mid d$, so $d$ is not a square.

Note, we did not use the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are primes, just the (clearly necessary) condition $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: I'm confused by one thing… Since changing $k$ increases $ap+1$ by leaps of $pq^2$, what's to say you will eventually hit a prime? Why couldn't all of the infinitude of primes in the progression $ap+1$ simply lie in the GAPS between each $kpq^2$ and the next-bigger $(k+1)pq^2$?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan, the progression that contains large primes is the progression $c, c+N, c+2N,\ldots$, where $c=(a_0p+1)/g$ and $N=pq^2/g$ with $g=\gcd(a_0p+1,pq^2)$.  The choice of $g$ means that $\gcd(c,N)=1$, so that Dirichlet's theorem applies.